An inequality of a sum
This inequality is from equation $\left(\bf 20\right)$ in this paper.
$\ell \geq 1$ is a variable related to the big O notation below.
$\gamma := \lfloor \log_{0.9}(1/l)\rfloor + 1$.
For $i \geq 1$, $\ell_i := 0.9^i \ell$
$L$ is a fixed positive constant.
The paper says that the fact $0.9 \leq \ell_{\gamma} < 1$ yields
$$\sum_{i\ =\ \gamma\ -\sqrt{\log_{0.9}(1/\ell)}}^{\gamma} (L\sqrt{\log \ell})^{-0.8 \ell_i} \leq O((L \sqrt{\log \ell})^{-c'})$$
I can't see how this inequality holds. Ignoring some constant multiplications, each term in the sum is less than $\sqrt{\log l}^{-0.8 \ell_{\gamma}}$ and the sum has $\sqrt{\log l}$-many terms. Hence this has an upper bound (up to constant muultiplication) $\sqrt{\log l}^{1 - 0.8 \ell_{\gamma}}$, but $1 - 0.8 \ell_{\gamma} > 0$, not negative. I think I'm missing something elementary facts.
Thank you in advance.

In summary: the sum is not best bounded by its largest term times the number of terms. Instead, it decays quickly enough away from its largest term that a better estimate for the sum is just that largest term.

In detail: the last term of the sum is somewhere between $(L \sqrt{\log\ell})^{-0.8}$ and $(L \sqrt{\log \ell})^{-0.72}$. Call that quantity $x$, and note that $x < 1$.
Renumbering the sum in terms of $j = \gamma-i$, we get the sum $$\sum_{j=0}^{\sqrt{\log_{0.9}(1/\ell)}} x^{0.9^{-j}}.$$ Taking the lower bound $0.9^{-j} = (1 + \frac19)^j \ge 1 + j/9$, we get an upper bound of $x^{0.9^{-j}} \le x^{1 + j/9}$ on each term. As a further bound, we can extend the sum to an infinite sum over all $j\ge 0$. This gives us the upper bound $$\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^{1 + j/9} = \frac{x}{1 - x^{1/9}} = O(x),$$ which is $O((L\sqrt{\log \ell})^{-c'})$ for $0.72 \le c' < 0.8$.
